# Should the tags 'atmega328', 'atmega8' and 'atmega16' be synonyms for the 'atmega' tags?

Tags: discussion

I think they should, similar to the ['pic' tag](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/pic/synonyms). I don't have enough reputation to even suggest it myself, but it might also be a good idea for the community to agree on whether chip families should be synonyms or not.

Comment: Related: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/180/857

Comment: If the consensus continues to swing towards "Yes", I'll merge these in a day or two.

Answer (score 1):

It has been done.

Thanks for the suggestion, and feel free to continue working on tags even though you don't officially have the privilege.

Comment: Thanks! I'll continue working on them, people are good at moderating my suggestions :)